# Disable autoscrolling in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm using UITableViewController with UITextField integrated in Cells as accessory view. The problem is that Cell (with UITextField) is automatically scrolled within TableView to visible area if a user tries to edit it. How can I disable this behavior?

I have tried to use

`self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;`

but it does not work.

Comment: Are you sure you're using a UITextField? Only UITextView supports multiline input.

Comment: I did not mention anything about multiline input... I'm using UITextField :)

Comment: How is it automatically scrolling?  Are you using something like `setContentOffset:`?

Comment: No, it is a default behavior of UITableViewController...

Comment: setScrollEnabled:NO should work.. it will not allow your tableview to scroll.. are you using some other code in textFieldDidBeginEditing

Comment: I guess I haven't worked with UITableViewController much, I always just write all the control into my UIViewController subclasses.  I wasn't aware it would autoscroll to a textfield.  Is it easy for your project to switch to a UIViewController subclass and control the scrolling more directly?

Comment: I'm writing a library and it must work with UITableViewController:(

Comment: I think to get it NOT to scroll you are going to have to look into implementing some of your own UITableViewDelegate methods.  Because this method accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath exists, it tells me that apple has implemented some default action they perform, and in order to change that, you will have to begin digging into implementing your own imlementations of some delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about this (roughly tested just now):

Create a `CGPoint` instance variable to hold the contentOffset.

In `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` or `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` set the `CGPoint` instance variable to the `UITableView`'s contentOffset.

In `scrollViewDidScroll:` check to see if the user is dragging. If it is, then set the `UITableView`'s contentOffset to the `CGPoint` instance variable.

Comment: I edited my answer to remove the boolean since I forgot you can easily check to see if the user is dragging.